# Python list of Literal type check error (same for dict with Literal keys) in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, mypy

I'd like to use advantages of Literal type hints in Python, but it seems that Literal is not recognized correctly as dict keys or in lists:

```
from typing import Literal, Dict, List

T = Literal['foo', 'bar']
L = List[T]
D = Dict[T, int]

q: T = 'foo'  # ok
l: L = ['foo', 'bar']  # Expected type 'List[Literal['foo', 'bar']]', got 'List[str]' instead 
d: D = {'foo': 1}  # Expected type 'Dict[Literal['foo', 'bar'], int]', got 'Dict[str, int]' instead
```

How do use Literal type correctly in list or as dict keys?

Comment: I think your example program type checks as-is in mypy. For example, see https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=483d192d72fc3316664899ade7b66bab. For Pycharm, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-41268 -- it seems this is a known bug on their end. The comments in the bug report suggest doing hacks like `l = cast(L, ['foo', 'bar'])` as a workaround. (If you aren't using mypy and only wanted to ask about type hints in pycharm, 'python-typing' or 'type-hinting' are perhaps better tags to use then 'mypy'.)